# unique filter not working properly in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple example where I am exptecting my paragraphs to filter out values based on unique age, but I get the unknown provider error. How ?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p ng-repeat="x in persons | unique: 'age'">{{x.name}}</p>
<script>
//App declaration
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
//Controller Declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.persons = [{name: "Peter",age:23},{name:"Laila",age:25},{name:"Rosy",age:23}];
});
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Angular doesn't have a unique filter. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter

Comment: I'm almost certain this is an angularui filter, not aware of a native one :)

Comment: There is no `unique` filter in angular (do search in https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js). Try using these utils https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject 'ui.directives' and 'ui.filters' module to your app

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ui.directive', 'ui.filters']);
```

Since ui.directives and ui.filters modules are present in AngularUI, you will also need to refer angular-ui.js in your application

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Your full code should look something like this

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p ng-repeat="x in persons | unique: 'age'">{{x.name}}</p>
<script>
//App declaration
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ui.directives','ui.filters']);
//Controller Declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.persons = [{name: "Peter",age:23},{name:"Laila",age:25},{name:"Rosy",age:23}];
});
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you need `ui.directives` module here, and `ui` version is very outdated `v0.4.0 - 2013-02-15`. It doesn't mean that `unique` won't work, but rather than adding overkill dependency, it's better to use just the filter, or write your own.

Comment: @sbedulin I agree with you. I gave the answer cause the question was why the unknown provider error was being thrown.

Answer (score 2):

That because the unique filter can currently be found as part of AngularJs UI Utils.
To make this work you must include it as an additional reference in your module `angular.module('myApp', ['ui', 'ui.filters']);`

Hope this help you.